# Why is my Eclipse JRE Library JDK 13 unbound?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-13

I imported a project but my JDK 13 JRE is unbound and i have a ton of errors because of that.

[image]
[image]

If i use another JDK version most of the errors are gone but i still have some left
f.e.:  The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java 
     Build Path

This is btw a school project about making a webinterface for a SQL example using jsp and tomcat server

EDIT:
SO JDK13 is not unbound anymore, but i still got the "The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path" Error. Is it because of the Server library still beeing unbound?[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with JSP at all,, but all the suggestion i saw is different than your code.
you wrote
`<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>`
suggested
`<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>`

Comment: The code is not the problem. I think it's about the implementation of JDK 13, but i am not sure either

Comment: Yes you are right that space has nothing to do. I did some test, First of all OpenJDK 13 did not drop `java.sql.*`. And I am guessing you are messing up project settings. In your first image there is a warning message. Please take a look at **Java Compiler** settings

Comment: Do you have an installed JRE on that preference page named "jdk-13"? You project's Java Build Path is set to refer to it by name, and that name must be specific to the preferences in the original workspace where it was created. `javax.servlet` packages would come out of targeting a Tomcat server runtime, which would have them.

Comment: Look in the Preferences at 'Java > Installled JREs' to see what Eclipse knows about.

Comment: So i my JDK13 was called "jdk-13.01" and i renamed it to "jdk-13" and most of the errors are gone and the JDK13 JRE is not unbound anymore. BUT i still have the The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path" Error. Is it because the Server Library Tomcat is still unbound?

Comment: Looks like the JAR file containing the `HttpServlet` class is not part of the _Build path_ for your project. You can edit the _Build path_ through the _Project properties_.

Comment: Redo your workspace.

Comment: Check the **Targeted Runtime** page in the project properties dialog you're showing. Like the JRE was pointing to one you don't have by name, the server runtime being targeted (from which those classes would be found) would also be invalid on a different workspace for the same reasons.